# Youtube autoplay on mobile with WiFi

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

So I understand based on the [Youtube API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations) as well as a few [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090782/youtube-autoplay-not-working-on-mobile-devices-with-embedded-html5-player) questions here on Stackoverflow that auto-play is not allowed for embedded media on Safari/Chrome on mobile devices. The rationale is to ensure unsolicited downloads don't happen over cellular networks. But if a user is on Chrome in a mobile device but is on Wi-Fi (which a lot of users are on typically), this restriction of disallowing autoplay seems to still exist via the Youtube iframe API. Why is this the case? Perhaps there is something I am missing. Appreciate any advice/pointers. I was hoping to achieve auto-play on mobile web if user is on WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not Youtube's Restrictions, it's (was) Apple's.

[New  Policies for iOS](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/)

You just need to add the correct html tag and attribute and it works on newer devices.