# How to Embed a Youtube Playlist in Mobile

Tags: mobile, youtube, youtube-api, embed, playlist

I have this code and I embed a Youtube playlist to my website

```
<iframe width="300" height="165" 
src="PLAYLIST_URL?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&loop=1&list=PLAYLIST_ID&rel=0" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This works in desktop and it auto play and loop. `But I can only listen one track in mobile and does not auto play` (iPhone 4S, iOS 7).

This is my webpage : [www.hqtunes.com](http://www.hqtunes.com/)

How can I fix the embed code and can auto play and loop, like on desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Based this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090782/youtube-autoplay-not-working-on-mobile-devices-with-embedded-html5-player), autoplay cannot be done on iOS and Android devices. For various [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009888/autoplay-audio-files-on-an-ipad-with-html5) (including, but not limited to data usage), Apple doesn't allow auto-playing of videos. You may also check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=fr#Mobile_considerations) which stated that *"Warning: To prevent unwanted downloads on mobile networks at the user's expense, playback of embedded media can not be launched automatically in Safari for iOS, and only the user can start playback."*

Comment: Okey, and I could not also play any of them even without autoplay on mobile. Is it restricted, too?