# Embedded Youtube video needs two clicks to play on mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I was trying to create a lazy-loaded embedded youtube video with a custom icon as a play button. It is created successfully and even it is working properly in the desktop view. On desktop when I click on play button once the video gets started.

However when I open the page on mobile view and click on play button it doesn't play and also after the first click it was showing the youtube default play button. After that when I clicked on the Youtube default play button it starts to play the video.

I want to only click once to play the video on mobile. Please help me out to rectify it and let me know where exactly I am wrong in the code.

```js
(function() {
  var youtube = document.querySelectorAll(".youtube");
  for (var i = 0; i < youtube.length; i++) {
    var source = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + youtube[i].dataset.embed + "/sddefault.jpg";
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = source;
    image.addEventListener("load", function() {
      youtube[i].appendChild(image);
    }(i));
    youtube[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
      iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
      iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "");
      iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.dataset.embed + "?rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1");
      this.innerHTML = "";
      this.appendChild(iframe);
    });
  };

})();
```

```css
.youtube {
  background-color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.youtube img {
  width: 100%;
  top: -16.84%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.youtube .play-button {
  width: 90px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.youtube .play-button:before {
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0 15px 26.0px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
}

.youtube img,
.youtube .play-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.youtube img,
.youtube iframe,
.youtube .play-button,
.youtube .play-button:before {
  position: absolute;
}

.youtube .play-button,
.youtube .play-button:before {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d( -50%, -50%, 0);
}

.youtube iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
  <!-- (2) the "play" button -->
  <div class="play-button"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there's no autoplay on mobile devices. If you simply load the video with that attribute the video won't start. Take a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090782/youtube-autoplay-not-working-on-mobile-devices-with-embedded-html5-player

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure that the author of this question wants the autoplay feature.

For what it's worth, I managed to embed a YouTube video in a way that you only need to click once on the player to run a video on a mobile device. In my opinion it's the matter of embedding the IFrame player from YT properly, so that you could use `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function.

Everything is quite well described here: [YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player)

Made a fiddle, not in a loop, but you'll get the idea:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sveg/e5mb5Lj1/2/)

Comment: I don't want autoplay instead I just want my video to play when someone clicks once on mobile view and also it should use lazy loading functionality so that the page will load faster on the browser.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. I've added a JSFiddle to my response, maybe you'll find it usefull.

Comment: Please include the code from the JSFiddle in the answer itself to comply with site rules and prevent link rot.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading that means auto play is allowed in mobile devices, rather add lazy load only to large devices using below media query remove lazy load for small devices like mobiles.

```
if($(window).width() < 767)
{
   // change functionality for smaller screens
} else {
   // change functionality for larger screens
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I managed to get videos to play with one click only on desktop/mobile with  very similar JavaScript as yours, except with the addition of the `onPlayerReady` function:

```js
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

If you're on WordPress, I've made a YouTube lazy loading plugin out of it. More info + demo here https://thinksmall.me/

If you're not on WordPress, feel free to open the plugin and view its code. The code is very close to yours with the loop. You'll see how to make it work with the `onPlayerReady` function.