# Youtube video does not playing on click of youtube thumb in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I have a list of youtube videos on my page. I have used below code which gets image cover of youtube video & while clicking on the youtube image cover it play the respective youtube video. But it works on desktop only. In a mobile device whenever I clicks on youtube image cover it shows again the youtube image with play button instead of playing youtube video directly.

Note: I don't have used any API like youtube iframe_api etc. It's simple iframe for each youtube video & written the below code to display youtube image cover.

```
function youTubes_makeDynamic() {
        var $ytIframes = jQuery('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]');
        $ytIframes.each(function (i,e) {
            var $ytFrame = jQuery(e);
            var ytKey; var tmp = $ytFrame.attr('src').split(/\//); tmp = tmp[tmp.length - 1]; tmp = tmp.split('?'); ytKey = tmp[0];
            var $ytLoader = jQuery('<div class="ytLoader">');
            $ytLoader.append(jQuery('<img alt="youtube" class="cover lazyload" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/'+ytKey+'/hqdefault.jpg">'));
            $ytLoader.append(jQuery('<i class="playBtn material-icons">play_circle_outline</i>'));
            $ytLoader.data('$ytFrame',$ytFrame);
            $ytFrame.replaceWith($ytLoader);
            $ytLoader.click(function () {
                var $ytFrame = $ytLoader.data('$ytFrame');
                $ytFrame.attr('src',$ytFrame.attr('src')+'?autoplay=1');
                $ytLoader.replaceWith($ytFrame);
            });
        });
    };
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {youTubes_makeDynamic()});
```

This the code I am using. It work on dekstop but it won't on mobile devices as per expectations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube autoplay not working on mobile devices with embedded HTML5 player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090782/youtube-autoplay-not-working-on-mobile-devices-with-embedded-html5-player)

Comment: @PeterBode checked already but not found related issue/solution..

Comment: So you know autoplay doesn't work on mobile, and still add the autoplay tag?

Comment: It works for deskptop that's why I added autoplay..also in mobile devices when I click on youtube image cover then also autoplay is added from the script but only the issue is it does not play automatically when I click on image cover in mobile devices