# Electron webview doesn't auto-play youtube videos

Tags: javascript, youtube, electron

Electron [webview](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag) doesn't auto-play youtube videos. I am using Electron version `4.0.4`

I send `autoplay=1` as mentioned in [Youtube docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en), but no luck.

In the same time, Youtube URL  auto-plays just fine in incognito Chrome window when copy/pasted.

Here is the simple code of `webview`

```
<webview id="youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1"></webview>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're testing this URL in a mobile device, it wont autoplay the video - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15093243/4092887), if you're testing this URL in a web browser, please check whether the console has errors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MauricioAriasOlave I am testing this on Desktop. No errors in console.

Comment: Try add the `&mute=1` after `autoplay=1`. I though it was due to mobile wont autoplay, but, even if with `&mute=1` added and since I don't know about `webView`, I'm affraid I can't help, sorry. Just curious, did you search on Google about if anyone else has this problem?