# How to start a youtube video from mouseover image click?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on website and came across to JavaScript and need HELP.

I have a Youtube video and two images. One image is shown when we display the site, then the second image is shown after mouseover. But this second image should also be a link to the video.
One major thing is that I WANT TO KEEP THE VIDEO in the same page (no pop-ups).
Also the sizes of the images are small, but the video should be resized.

So far I know how to do the mouseover, but do not know how to make the video work in the same page.
Thanks

My code of mouseover ---

```
<img src="1.png" onmouseover="this.src='2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='1.png'"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this answer:
[start/play embedded (iframe) youtube-video on click of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246939/start-play-embedded-iframe-youtube-video-on-click-of-an-image)

You can put your Youtube video inside of an iFrame and do the same thing except instead of a click() you'll be using mouseover/mouseout as you are.