# yt api, jquery and pagination - weird behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-javascript-api

I try to make a video wall with multiple iframes, video should play when user hovers over the video iframe. 
Everything I set in the code works -  I can call currentPlayer.seekTo(10) and it moves the slider but currentPlayer.playVideo() doesn't work.

And the weird part is than if I hover on a card - this creates or chooses a player from an array and set it to global vriable and I call this player manually from the console by

```
currentPlayer.playVideo()
```

All the code suddenly starts to work for that player, 
When I first manually call a function (does not matter which: playVideo, mute) on all the players my website starts to work as intended. I can hover between videos and only the one where the mouse is positioned is working.

html part of the code is here but in the bin it does not work at all, it's just for reference how it looks.
https://jsbin.com/bavexujome/edit?html,js,output
my js looks like this:

```
//yt api boilerplate

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// my helper variables

var players = {}
var player
var currentPlayerId = null
var currentPlayer = null

// I have cards with iframes inside - when user hovers on a card 
// then I check if I have a player for that card in my players array 
//and if not I create it and set it to global variable
// I also try to start that video first time I got the autoplay 
// variable set - dont work and it there is a player I try to call
// .playvideo() on it - also does not work 
// all variables are set proper - I can console.log them

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hg-container').on("mouseenter", ".card", function(){
    currentPlayerId = $(this).find('iframe').attr('id');
    player = $(this).find('iframe')[0];

    if (!players[currentPlayerId]){
      players[currentPlayerId] = new YT.Player(player, {
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1 },
        events: {'onReady': onPlayerReady }
      });
    }
    else{
      currentPlayer = players[currentPlayerId]
      currentPlayer.playVideo();
    }
  });

  //when user leaves the card video should stop

  $('#hg-container').on("mouseleave", ".card", function(){
    currentPlayer.pauseVideo();
    currentPlayer = null;
  });
});

  //this gets called when video loads - and seekTo(10) works
  // but playVideo() don't

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  currentPlayer = players[currentPlayerId]
  currentPlayer.seekTo(10);
  currentPlayer.playVideo();
}

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
  console.log("ready")
}
```

Any hint's ? I think it might be a scope problem and when I call this from js console the scope somehow changes and then it works

Comment: Take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706799/start-youtube-video-on-hover-mouseover

Comment: You just want to play and pause the video or you also want to seek?

Comment: @sridharreddy on this page there is a jsfiddle and I have similar problem - I have to first interact with one of the videos then it all start to work.
I now checked my code in palemoon browser and it works  - maybe recent chrome and firefox have some safety turned on - I got lot of js errors in the console when loading the videos which are not present in palemoon