# Play video on link click in an ASP.Net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to implement the functionality of playing video on clicking a link in an ASP.Net website.

What options do I have available? I have googled and have found that we can also use JQuery for this.

But I'm still not sure about it.

Comment: Sorry, but Stackoverflow is for asking specific questions about what you already have - it is not for asking for tutorials or working code. Please read the [ask] section in the help

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for this:

[start/play embedded (iframe) youtube-video on click of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246939/start-play-embedded-iframe-youtube-video-on-click-of-an-image)

Your going to need JQuery, @Anuj Khandelwal gave good example hope it helps

Comment: i need to play a video file from a shared location not from you tube\